# Using same login form to login into Admin and User accounts in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I am using Passport Js for authentication and have two local authentication strategies -- `student` and `admin` defined. Currently, I am using two different routes `/admin/login` and `/student/login` to sign in. These two different routes receive POST requests from two different forms and use appropriate local strategies to authenticate.

I would like to only use one route `/login` for both admins and students to sign in. How can I achieve that with my current setup?

Comment: Are an admin and a student differ only by user rights?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same schema for both of the user types, i.e. User and Admin, then add a new Boolean value inside the schema which signifies whether a user is an Admin or not.

E.g.:
(If you are using Mongoose)

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  isAdmin: {type:Boolean, default:false},
});
```

You should also add the respective field in the form of a dropdown menu, or radio button when registering a new user.

Now you can use the same POST route for logging in both kinds of users, and the isAdmin property of the logged in user can be used to differentiate them and also change the things that appear for different users.

For e.g. if you're using "ejs" as your view engine, then

```
<% if(currentUser.isAdmin) { %>
<p> You can see this! </p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: `student` and `admin` schemas differ in more than just that. `student` is a student at a university while `admin` is the employee at the university.